# How to make pie chart label not overlapping in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, pie-chart

The pie chart that i have made is like below image.

[image: piechart]

However i want the label (inside the pie chart) to be shown around the pie chart, and when the data is zero, the label will not be shown so it will not be overlapping. Can someone teach me how to do it? Thank you in advance :)

Here is my coding in Java

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

public class MyRecyclerViewPer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewPer.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
   ArrayList <Integer> tlist;
    TextView swipe;
    String[] disorder = {"a", "b", "c","d","e"};
    int[] one = new int[5];
    int[] two = new int[5];
    int[] three = new int[5];
    int[] four = new int[5];
    int[] five = new int[5];


    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;

    public MyRecyclerViewPer(Context c, ArrayList <Integer> t, int[] o, int[] tw, int[] th, int[] fo,int[] fi){
        context=c;
        tlist=t;
        one=o;
        two=tw;
three=th;
four=fo;
five=fi;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
        TextView tname,sc,o,t,th,fo,fi;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        PieChart pieChart;
        PieData pieData;
        PieDataSet pieDataSet;
        ArrayList pieEntries;
        ArrayList PieEntryLabels;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            sc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.score);
            tname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            o=itemView.findViewById(R.id.one);
           t=itemView.findViewById(R.id.two);
            th=itemView.findViewById(R.id.three);
            fo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.four);
            fi=itemView.findViewById(R.id.five);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            swipe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            swipe.setText("<<< Swipe left or right to refresh >>>");

            pieChart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);

            pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();

          pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "");
            pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
            pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
            pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);
            pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(5f);
            pieDataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(90.f);
            pieDataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(.10f);
            pieDataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(.50f);


        }




    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chart,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tname.setText(disorder[position]);
        holder.sc.setText(String.valueOf(tlist.get(position)));
        holder.o.setText(String.valueOf(one[position]));
        holder.t.setText(String.valueOf(two[position]));
        holder.th.setText(String.valueOf(three[position]));
        holder.fo.setText(String.valueOf(four[position]));
        holder.fi.setText(String.valueOf(five[position]));

        holder.pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();


    holder.pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(one[position], "Normal"));


            holder.pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(two[position], "Mild"));


            holder.pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(three[position], "Moderate"));


            holder.pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(four[position], "Severe"));

            holder.pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(five[position], "Very severe"));


        holder.pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(holder.pieEntries, "");
        holder.pieData = new PieData(holder.pieDataSet);
        holder.pieChart.setData(holder.pieData);
        holder.pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
        holder.pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
        holder.pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);
        holder.pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(5f);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tlist.size();
    }



}
```

Comment: My final solution is: don't display the small values. e.g. only display the values bigger than 5%.

Comment: Which library you are using?

Comment: @ParthLotia  thank you for your reply,  i am using this 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha' from internet

Comment: when you don't want to show labels set  `chart.setDrawEntryLabels(false)` and change this to true when you want to show. Don't forget to call `invalidate()` when you hide/show the labels

Comment: I think you need to apply one condition like `If(entry.getVal()>0) {} `.